# SQL average of previous range of columns into current column

Tags: sql, oracle, lag

I am trying to get the following calculations but at row level, in the image below I calculated the avg of values for each day (it can have n number of rows) then I used the LAG function to insert the avg of the previous row into the next row LAG_VAL column.

[image: group by calculation]

Now I am doing the calculations at row level, I have been able to get the average for that range of data using windowed functions (analytics)

```
ROUND(AVG(SUMCOUNTSFT3) OVER (partition by to_date(to_char(DATETIMEOFREADING, 'DD/MM/RRRR'))),2) as AVG_SUMCOUNTSFT3
```

but I have been not able to calculate the avg value of the previous day an insert that into the range of the next day as illustrated in the previous image.

[image: row level calculation]

Not sure if there is a way to implement this with the RANGE function of if I need to use PLSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head (without a matching schema to test with) this windowing clause should work:

```
(partition by to_date(to_char(DATETIMEOFREADING, 'DD/MM/RRRR') order by dates range between interval '1' day preceding and interval '1' day preceding)
```

This is plain SQL, so it works inside as well as outside of PL/SQL.

Comment: thanks, I was able to solve this with your suggestions. interval key word was missing after the AND. 

ROUND(AVG(SUMCOUNTSFT3) OVER (order by to_date(to_char(DATETIMEOFREADING, 'DD/MM/RRRR')) RANGE between interval '1' day preceding AND interval '1' day preceding),2) as  AVG_DAYS_BEFORE

Comment: Great it worked! I approved the edit, so the everyone who might be interested can use the answer right away, without reading the comments.